# Sandcastle Help File Builder Crash

Tags: xml-documentation, sandcastle

When you click the Edit API Filter button (visibility tab), SHFB v2018.7.8.0 crashes.

Answer (score 0):

While adding XMLDOC I accidentally wrote this code:

```
/// [Browsable(false)]
```

When I fixed it the problem went away. I confirmed that SHFB version 2020.3.6.0 does not crash when it encounters that construct. Of course, the Browsable attribute doesn't work until you move it out from inside the XMLDOC.